# EFCore Execute Stored Procedure and get resulting SELECT statement as a DataTable or List<Object>

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, ado.net

I currently have a stored procedures that could return different types of data depending on the arguments passed. i.e:

```
EXEC spGetData 'CAR'
```

Will execute:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Car
```

```
EXEC spGetData 'TRUCK'
```

Will execute:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Truck
```

I want to execute this stored procedure from EFCore 5 and without using ADO.NET if possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. This is not what EF Core is for.

Comment: Instead, use Dapper.